# Best way to serialize a byte array key to Redis with Booksleeve

Tags: redis, booksleeve

I need to find the best implementation to send a byte array to the key space of a Redis Server with Booksleeve.

I tried different implementation like UTF8 Encoding but i don't know what is the most optimized one in memory of redis server (i will worked with millions of key like this so i really need the shortest in memory key).

Is anyone has already had this requirement?

Comment: Redis supports binary data. You don't need to encode anything to send a byte array to Redis.

Comment: I have noticed that we could send binary in value but i don't find any method to send a key in binary with booksleeve wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

In the current build for simplicity I've stuck to string keys, however the code would handle binary fine - it uses the binary API. IIRC I received a patch in my inbox just this week that adds binary key support.

Since it seems to be in demand I'll look at that this week.

---

Edit: a week came and went; the reason being that I'm also doing some work on redis-cluster support, which is going to need some new interfaces *anyway*, because:

- not all operations are supported
- parallel (numbered) databases aren't supported

So basically my plan is to roll both pieces of work into the same branch, giving:

- a new set of interfaces

  - which use a `struct` for the `key` parameter with an implicit conversion operator from `string` and `byte`, allowing either to be used interchangeably
  - with the redis-cluster and redis-server commands on separate APIs
  - and a new method on the old connection to get one of the new APIs on a per-DB basis, i.e. `Database(3).Keys.Remove(key);` or something like that

ETA is still imaginary, but I wanted to explain why I hadn't simply thrown in the existing patch - I think the advent of redis-cluster makes it a good time to revisit the entire API, (but obviously in a way that doesn't break existing code).

Comment: Glad that you can work on this feature. Would you have an approximate date of this dev? Anyway, thank you for your great lib

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will test your api as soon as it will be release on nuget.

Comment: I use your api in production since this week and it work exactly that i would expected, great job!